# ClassNotFound exception when attempting to use DataflowRunner

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to launch a Dataflow job on GCP using Apache Beam 0.6.0.  I am compiling an uber jar using the shade plugin because I cannot launch the job using "mvn:execjava". I'm including this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown 'runner' specified 'DataflowRunner', supported pipeline runners [DirectRunner]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1609)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:289)
    at com.disney.dtss.desa.tools.SpannerSinkTest.main(SpannerSinkTest.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataflowRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1595)
```

Am I missing something else?

Comment: That is definitely the expected output if the DataflowRunner is not registered. Can you share anything more about your pom.xml, your mvn invocation, or perhaps a listing of the contents of your uber jar and how you invoke it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It works fine when I start the pipeline though `mvn compile exec:java`, when I build jar it fails. The uberjar contains the necessary classes.

Answer (score 10):

try

`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Yourmain Class -Pdataflow-runner`

*add -Pdataflow-runner at the last

Comment: In `pom.xml`, if the dependency is defined as part of a profile, make sure to specify the profile for the `mvn` command. The default WordCount example from Apache Beam does this for the `DataflowRunner`. If you don't care about profiles, just move the dependency definition to the `<dependencies>` section of the pom file.

Answer (score 3):

Following [@Andrew Nguonly's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937284/classnotfound-exception-when-attempting-to-use-dataflowrunner/60735533#comment84677175_43812941) I copied the dependency for `DataflowRunner` to outer scope (to the `<dependencies>` tag) in the `pom.xml` file.

Basically added this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Before the closing `</dependencies>` at `pom.xml` from the beam wordCount example.

Comment: For VSCode users, the above method might be the best bet as there isn't yet a clean way to switch profiles: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/465